# MATLAB : how to make a comparison in a for loop with indexes

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vector

At the end of the for loop l want to compare the values of I(i) and I(j) look at the second for loop.
 here is the returned error : 
??? Attempted to access I(2); index out of bounds because numel(I)=1.

Error in ==> eliminationphase at 143 if (I(i)==I(j)&&(j < i))

Look at the code below:

```
 alpha= 10;
       W=1;
       I=1;
       for i=1:N
              if (~ismember(num2str(i), num2str(F)))
                     while((C(i) < alpha) && (W < N))
                           if ((i~=W) && (ismember(W, neighbour_n{i})))
                               C(i)=C(i)+C(W);
                               display(['la somme des cardinaux de ', num2str(i), ' is   ', num2str(C(i))]);
                               I(i)=I(i)+1;
                               display(['The number of iteration of  ', num2str(i), ' is   ', num2str(I(i))]);
                               W=W+1;
                           else
                               W=W+1;
                           end  
                     end
              end
              if (~ismember(num2str(i), num2str(F)))
              display(['the value of the node:  ', num2str(i), '   at the end of while is ;  ', num2str(C(i))]); 
              end
       end
% l need to retreive the all the values of I and compare between them and between thein indices
   for i=1:N
         for j=1:N
             if (((~ismember(num2str(i), num2str(F)))&&(~ismember(num2str(i), num2str(F))))&&(i~=j))
                if (I(i)==I(j)&&(j < i))
                    display(i);
                end 
                 if (I(i) >I(j))
                    display(i);
                 end 
             end
         end  
     end
```

Comment: size of I in the first loop depend on some conditions, hens it might not fill I to the size of N

Comment: As mentioned by @user3528438, the size of I depends on multiple conditions. I would suggest initializing I to a vector of zeros: I=zeros(N,1).